# find open and close status using mysql

Tags: mysql

I've restaurant table with restaurant open & close time for week days (mon to sun). I need to find the restaurant status using opening & closing time. And also I need to list first opening restaurant then closed restaurant.

```
restaurant table
----------------
resid   resname
1   Res1
2   Res2
3   Res3
4   Res4
5   Res5
6   Res6
7   Res7



restaurant_time
----------------
resid   mon_otime   mon_ctime   tue_otime   tue_ctime   wed_otime   wed_ctime   thu_opentime
1   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
2   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
3   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
4   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
5   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
6   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
7   10:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   06:00   23.30   10:00
```

I want to list the output like below...

```
resid   resname Restaurant_status
1   Res1    open
3   Res3    open
4   Res4    open
7   Res7    open
2   Res2    closed
5   Res5    closed
6   Res6    closed
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by first opening snd closing restsurant? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. You should normalise this table.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any idea. so Please explain me, how I write a mysql query.

Comment: What do you mean by first opening snd closing restsurant?
I need to list first open status resturants then list closed status restaurants.

Answer (score 0):

To start, if I were tackling this problem, I'd normalize `restaurant_time`:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant_time
(
  resid        INT,
  dayofweek    INT,
  opentime     TIME,
  closetime    TIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (resid, dayofweek),
  FOREIGN KEY (resid) REFERENCES restaurant (resid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Then I'd create a function to determine if a given restaurant is open at a given time:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_open(rest_id INT, theday INT, thetime TIME)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
  BEGIN
    DECLARE otime TIME;
    DECLARE ctime TIME;
    SELECT opentime, closetime
      INTO otime, ctime
      FROM restaurant_times t
      WHERE t.resid = rest_id
        AND t.dayofweek = theday;
    IF (TIMEDIFF(opentime, thetime) < 0)
        AND (TIMEDIFF(thetime, closetime) < 0) THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
  END;
```

Finally, the query

```
SELECT r.resid, r.name,
    IF(is_open(r.resid, DAYOFWEEK(NOW()), TIME(NOW())), "open", "closed")
  FROM restaurant r;
```

should give you the desired result.

**NOTE** that the preceding code has not been tested in any way and is in no way guaranteed to be free of syntax errors.